# Python module installation

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, installation

we are unable to install new python modules to my computer using pip

installation error on pycharm

[image: X]

Installation error on cmd

[image: X]

Answer (score 1):

This is just a downloading problem. You should check your internet connection.

You should either try later or through a different network (in case the access to the website is blocked on your current network.) You might also try to use a VPN.

P.S.: I've just tried to install scrapy via pip, and I didn't encounter any problem.